# Bar button item is not being added

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

Im facing a problem, i have a `viewController` that has both `navigationController` and `tabBarController`. Whenever in code i try to add a right or left `barButtonItem` or even to add a title to the `navigationBar` nothing happens. Is it because of the tab bar? or what might the problem be

in `viewDidLoad`

```
let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(ProfileVC.addNewService))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
```

here how the view controller look in the storyboard

[image]

Comment: are you trying to add barbutton in navigation bar? if yes, self.navigationbar should be present while adding button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
parentViewController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
```

since your TabBarController is embedded in NavigationController like this:

UINavigationController -> UITabBarcontroller -> YourViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh, target: self, action: "buttonMethod")
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    }

    func buttonMethod() {
        print("Perform action")
    }

}
```

are using Custom bar button Try this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       let btnName = UIButton()
       btnName.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), forState: .Normal)
       btnName.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
       btnName.addTarget(self, action: Selector("action"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

       //.... Set Right/Left Bar Button item
       let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
       rightBarButton.customView = btnName
       self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton

    }

    func action() {
        print("Perform action")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your navigationcontroller's rootviewcontroller is TabbarController
so you must create customized UITabbarController class then push your source code into viewDidload function of the customized UITabbarController.

Tree viewcontroller will be: *NavigationController --> UITabbarController->ViewController*

Or You should set navigationcontroller for each ViewController in TabBarController

Tree viewcontroller will be: *UITabbarController->NavigationController->ViewController*